# "Vue: Unknown at rule @apply" in IntelliJ IDEA despite official Tailwind plugin

Tags: vue.js, intellij-idea, tailwind-css, apply

I'm having issues using the `@apply` rule. It is marked as "Unknown" in my Vue files, despite having the official bundled Tailwind plugin enabled

[image]

[image]

These are my Plugin Settings, which I even have extended with an additional line for Vue, without any impact.

```
{
  "includeLanguages": {
    "ftl": "html",
    "jinja": "html",
    "jinja2": "html",
    "smarty": "html",
    "tmpl": "gohtml",
    "cshtml": "html",
    "vbhtml": "html",
    "razor": "html",
    "vue": "vue" //manually added
  },
  "files": {
    "exclude": [
      "**/.git/**",
      "**/node_modules/**",
      "**/.hg/**",
      "**/.svn/**"
    ]
  },
  "emmetCompletions": false,
  "classAttributes": ["class", "className", "ngClass"],
  "colorDecorators": false,
  "showPixelEquivalents": true,
  "rootFontSize": 16,
  "hovers": true,
  "suggestions": true,
  "codeActions": true,
  "validate": true,
  "lint": {
    "invalidScreen": "error",
    "invalidVariant": "error",
    "invalidTailwindDirective": "error",
    "invalidApply": "error",
    "invalidConfigPath": "error",
    "cssConflict": "warning",
    "recommendedVariantOrder": "warning"
  },
  "experimental": {
    "configFile": null,
    "classRegex": []
  }
}
```

**What do I have to do to make IntelliJ IDEA aware of the `@apply` rule?**

Comment: Does the issue persist in the same project in a CSS file? Is it reproducible in a new Vue project? I couldn't reproduce it so far.

Comment: @Oksana will have to test that, as I currently only have smaller CSS rules in the vue files directly

Comment: @Oksana sorry for the late response. the `@apply` rule does work in scss files for example, but not in .vue files

Comment: Which Tailwind version do you use? Is the project located locally? What does your tailwind config file look like?

Comment: @Oksana in my project, I'm using UnoCSS and not Tailwind and the root of the project has the unocss config, but does that even matter to the IDE where this rule is coming from?

Comment: There is no UnoCSS support in IntelliJ IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-59407/UnoCSS-Support. You can try this third-party plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22204-unocss.